# Why am i losing data after clearing variable

Tags: c

I've got a function which adds a structure to my List of structures. After performing this function i want to Clear (assign NULL) to every single char[i], but unfortunatelly after doing that I'm losing a data from my list! I thought after assigment i do not need to worry about these data. Why is it so?

**File with problem**

```
char name[20], surname[20], id[12];

            addToList(head, &name, &surname, &id); // Everything here is fine
            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
            {
                name[i] = NULL; // after performing this i lose data from head!
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
            {
                surname[i] = NULL; // after performing this i lose data from head!
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
            {
                id[i] = NULL; // after performing this i lose data from head!
            }
```

Funtion **addToList**

```
void addToList(struct List * head, char *name, char *surname, char *id)
{
    struct List *tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct List));
    tmp = head;
    struct Person *newPerson = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
    newPerson->id = id;
    newPerson->name = name;
    newPerson->surname = surname;

    if (tmp->person == NULL)
    {
        head->next = malloc(sizeof(struct List));
        head->person = newPerson;
        head->next = NULL;
    }

/* Futher code */
```

Comment: What is the type of `name`? Your code is very broken, please post the declaration of `name`, and listen to your compiler, it must be telling you that something isn't quite right, if it isn't, enable compilation warnings.

Comment: name, and other variables are char tables

Comment: `tmp = malloc`, `tmp = head` ... you're leaking memory.

Comment: `newPerson->id = id;`, `newPerson->name = name;`, `newPerson->surname = surname;` - this doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't assign a `NULL` which is a pointer to a `char` element, you need

```
name[0] = '\0';
```

that's equivalent to clearing it in terms of how a string is represented in memory.

You are passing the wrong type to your function, and you should really read more about pointers and understand, that they point to memory and when you modify that memory in one place, you will have the effects propagated everywhere.

So first fix yor program in terms of correctness, you are passing incompatible types and you should allow your compiler to tell you about that, also fix the memory leak mentioned in comments, after that learn how to copy the contents of memory instead of assigning pointers, and your code should work correctly.

Because as it is, your structure members are almost pointing to the same memory as your "*temporary*" variables. I say almost, because your are using the `&` operator to pass them to the function when you shouldn't.

To make a summary of problems in your code

1. You can't assign `NULL` to a `char` type, `NULL` is a pointer, and `char` is not.
2. You MUST NOT use `&` the address of operator to pass the arrays to the `addToList()` function, because then the type of the passed object is not the same as that of the expected parameter, and even though it's working now it's wrong. I works, because the address of the array and the address of it's first element are the same, but `&name + 1` and `name + 1` have different addresses, so `strdup()` will not work correctly if you don't fix that.
3. You don't need to allocate memory for a temporary pointer, a pointer simply points to memory, it doesn't store data. If you want to point to `head`, just do it,

   ```
   tmp = head;
   ```

   is perfectly valid, but after that whatever you do to `head` will happen to `tmp` and vice versa.
4. You need to copy the data inside the `addToList()` function, because of what I said about pointers in the previous paragraph, to do so use `strdup()`, but remember to fix the `&` mistake.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer! I'll try to fix all matters you have mentioned. I do appreciate that

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that if you alter `name` elsewhere, it also changes `newPerson->name` because they're both pointing at the same place in memory. Instead, what you have to do is make a copy of `name` like this

```
newPerson->name = strdup(name);
```

This will allocate enough memory to store a new copy of `name` and then copy it into the new memory. It won't allocate memory of the same size if `name` doesn't fully occupy it.

```
char name[100]="test"; // name is 100 bytes in size
char *name2=strdup(name); // name2 is 5 bytes in size
```

Comment: That's not really happening, if you are rigorous. Please take a closer look at the code. There are many other problems.

Comment: Yes, there are a great many problems with this code, but if you read the question the primary confusion is that assigning a `char *` to another `char *` copies it such that they can change the other variable and it won't affect the "copy".